# Add tags to files and directories on file browser

Tags: gnome, files, gnome-shell, 19.04

I'd like to add a tag to the files or directories (tag=simbol). This tag would be visible on Files (3.32.1-stable).
I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tagging files on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830157/tagging-files-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not want a searchable tag, I want a visual tag. The post I'm being directed is  searchable tag related.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which files/directories? According to what criteria? What do you mean by visual? Do you want to set specific icons for each file/directory in the `Files` application?

Comment: On the Files application, I'd like to add a visual marker on a directory (or file). This marker would be a small figure, icon or emoticon, something to attract attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a file or directory in `Files` application, right click, and select **Properties** (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). On the **Basic** tab, click on the icon and select an appropriate `.png`, `.jpg` etc. file to set a *different icon* for the file or directory you have selected.

Comment: Thank you. This will do for what I need.